# Is there a tool that can mimic MS Paint Selection + Shift + Arrow?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, figma, ms-paint

I know this sounds silly, but this one of the reasons I prefer to work on Windows – one feature in MS Paint...

When you select something in MS Paint, you can move that selection with arrow keys. If you also hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key – somehow it will “patch” the hole with pixels of your selection. Basically, you can easily stretch/move simple UI elements like buttons.

Below is an example of stretching GMail logo.

[image: example of MSPaint feature]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. sorry, but the result looks terrible though; all the pixels are jagged. Do what @xenoid has suggested, and you'll get a much better result. [see example](https://imgur.com/F46AYF4) - also no need for all those key presses.

Answer (score 2):

In Gimp (and possibly PS):

- Increase the canvas size and split your object:
  [image]
- Create a one pixel-wide selection
  [image]
- Copy-paste it (Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V):
  [image]
- Use the Scale tool to stretch it:
  [image]
  (use `InterPolation: None`)
- And then Anchor it (Ctrl-H):
  [image]

---